# CSS/HTML why is this absolute positioned link not at the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, absolute

I am trying to place the 'learn more' link at the bottom of the page, it is text alone with the image of a red dot.

1) the image of the red dot and text are not centered using the 'centered' class
2) the link is not placed at the bottom of the page when I use absolute positioning of the link inside a div that is position:relative

Can someone help explain this to me? Thank you very much.

http://jsfiddle.net/7Kgxz/

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="page1">
    <nav class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Support</li>
            <li>Sign Up</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="page1-content centered">
        <h1> Generic Header</h1>
        <h2> Generic Content 1</h2>
        <h2> Generic Content 2</h2>
        <h2> Generic Content 3</h2>    
  </div>    

  <div class="learn-more centered">
    <a href="#learn" id="click"> learn more </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="page2-content" id="text">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}

.centered {
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center; 
}
nav {
  list-style: none;

}

.navigation ul li { 
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
    margin: 5px;
}

.page1-content {
    clear:both;
}

div.wrap {
    position:relative;
}
div.learn-more {
    position:relative;
}

.learn-more a {
background:url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wieringen/tinycircleslider/master/examples/simple/images/bg-dot.png) no-repeat;                
    height: 12px; 
    width: 12px;
    color:red;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.page2-content {
    margin: 200px 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    background-size: 100% 1000px;
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for "learn more" link on bottom of the blue div tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements are positioned within the closest parent which is explicitly positioned.

You've added `position: relative;` to your `.centered`, which is the immediate parent of the link you're positioning absolutely. That link will be positioned absolutely *within `.centered`*, not within the page.

If you want to position the element within the page and not within `.centered`, remove `position: relative;` from all the elements you've applied it to. There is no reason to explicitly specify it *except* to force child elements to be positioned relative to a specific element.

Comment: okay, thank you. I am starting to understand better. I removed the relative positioning and the element is now absolutely positioned at the bottom like it should be, however, it is not centered. But if I removed the background image, it becomes centered. Can you tell me why this is happening and how to get the image and text centered?

Comment: okay, I added the 'centered' class to the link itself, and everything becomes centered. But I am confused why it does not work when applied to the parent div?

Answer (score 0):

your "learn-more" immediate after "centered" class. this "centered" class has position also. so removed "centered" class from this element otherwise take new class for that element.